# How to get complex soap response using java web-service?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, netbeans

i have create a web service to add two numbers using netbeans...and i am getting the following response

```
SOAP Response

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <S:Body>
        <ns2:AddResponse xmlns:ns2="http://calculator.me.org/">
            <return>9</return>
        </ns2:AddResponse>
    </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

Bu i need to generate the soap response xml of the following structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
<CalculatedValue>9</CalculatedValue>
<response>
```

my java code:

```
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;

/**
 *
 * @author User
 */
@WebService(serviceName = "CalculatorWS")
@Stateless()
public class CalculatorWS {

    /**
     * This is a sample web service operation
     */
    @WebMethod(operationName = "hello")
    public String hello(@WebParam(name = "name") String txt) {
        return "<a>" + txt + "</a>";
    }

    /**
     * Web service operation
     */
    @WebMethod(operationName = "Add")
    public int Add(@WebParam(name = "i") int i, @WebParam(name = "j") int j) {
        //TODO write your implementation code here:
        int k=i+j;
        return k;

    }
}
```

wsdl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!-- Generated by JAX-WS RI at http://jax-ws.dev.java.net. RI's version is Metro/2.1.1-b09 (branches/2.1-6834; 2011-07-16T17:14:48+0000) JAXWS-RI/2.2.5-promoted-b04 JAXWS/2.2. -->
<definitions targetNamespace="http://calculator.me.org/" name="CalculatorWS" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:wsp="http://www.w3.org/ns/ws-policy" xmlns:tns="http://calculator.me.org/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsp1_2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
  <types>
    <xsd:schema>
      <xsd:import namespace="http://calculator.me.org/" schemaLocation="CalculatorWS_schema1.xsd"/>
    </xsd:schema>
  </types>
  <message name="hello">
    <part name="parameters" element="tns:hello"/>
  </message>
  <message name="helloResponse">
    <part name="parameters" element="tns:helloResponse"/>
  </message>
  <message name="Add">
    <part name="parameters" element="tns:Add"/>
  </message>
  <message name="AddResponse">
    <part name="parameters" element="tns:AddResponse"/>
  </message>
  <portType name="CalculatorWS">
    <operation name="hello">
      <input wsam:Action="http://calculator.me.org/CalculatorWS/helloRequest" message="tns:hello"/>
      <output wsam:Action="http://calculator.me.org/CalculatorWS/helloResponse" message="tns:helloResponse"/>
    </operation>
    <operation name="Add">
      <input wsam:Action="http://calculator.me.org/CalculatorWS/AddRequest" message="tns:Add"/>
      <output wsam:Action="http://calculator.me.org/CalculatorWS/AddResponse" message="tns:AddResponse"/>
    </operation>
  </portType>
  <binding name="CalculatorWSPortBinding" type="tns:CalculatorWS">
    <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>
    <operation name="hello">
      <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
      <input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </output>
    </operation>
    <operation name="Add">
      <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
      <input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </output>
    </operation>
  </binding>
  <service name="CalculatorWS">
    <port name="CalculatorWSPort" binding="tns:CalculatorWSPortBinding">
      <soap:address location="REPLACE_WITH_ACTUAL_URL"/>
    </port>
  </service>
</definitions>
```

i searched a lot on this....but didn't get any answer.I found a similar post in stackoverflow with no correct answer.How to generate that particular soap response using the web-service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to get a reply like the one you posted. By definition a SOAP document (or message) must contain an `Envelope` and at least the `Body` element. See more in the [SOAP specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/NOTE-SOAP-20000508/#_Toc478383494).

Your only control is over the contents of the `Body` element, by specifying the operation style to be RPC (remote procedure call) or document (plain XML).

Comment: Is it possible to generate atleast this type of respone:                 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <S:Body>
        <ns2:AddResponse xmlns:ns2="http://calculator.me.org/">
            <response>
<CalculatedValue>9</CalculatedValue>
<response>
        </ns2:AddResponse>
    </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>

Comment: Also if i want to add one more element with CalculatedValue\return in the same level how will i achieve that?

Comment: @soumitra chatterjee: You mean to return multiple values from the method?

Comment: You could try to create a complex type with both results and return it.

Comment: Return array of values. And you will see multiple values in responce

Comment: Return array of values helped.Can i change the <return> to something else of my choice